# Updated with join and ranking in MySQL query not working

Tags: mysql, join, rank

I've tried lots of query using answers from previous questions but can't seem to get it to work.

I get 6 results when I run this query (which is what I want), the first collun is the value a would like to update

```
select ranks.rank,ranks.vad as ran,id.* from ideias id
inner JOIN 
(
    SELECT p.codigo as vad,
    @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
    FROM ideias p
    JOIN (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
        where concat(DATE_FORMAT(p.data_envio,'%Y'),'-',DATE_FORMAT(p.data_envio,'%m'))='2016-09'
            or concat(DATE_FORMAT(p.data_nova_chance,'%Y'),'-',DATE_FORMAT(p.data_nova_chance,'%m'))='2016-09' 
            and p.Nota is not null
        ORDER BY p.Nota DESC , p.data_envio ASC, p.retorno_esperado ASC
) ranks ON ranks.vad = id.codigo
where id.Nota is not null
```

This is the result:

[image: Values]

It's correct if you look the field `rank` and `codigo`, this is the update I would like
But, when I run this query:

```
UPDATE   ideias id
inner JOIN 
(
    SELECT p.codigo as vad, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
        FROM ideias p
        JOIN (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
            where concat(DATE_FORMAT(p.data_envio,'%Y'),'-',DATE_FORMAT(p.data_envio,'%m'))='2016-09'
                or concat(DATE_FORMAT(p.data_nova_chance,'%Y'),'-',DATE_FORMAT(p.data_nova_chance,'%m'))='2016-09' 
                and p.Nota is not null
            ORDER BY p.Nota DESC , p.data_envio ASC, p.retorno_esperado ASC
) ranks ON ranks.vad = id.codigo
SET id.Posicao = ranks.rank
where id.Nota is not null
```

The update was wrong, look the picture with the result:

[image]

Comment: facing same issue. I don't know why this happens it set auto Incremental key of codigo when it bulk updating. Not sure but it's bug of mysql. Same type of query worked on other server